# find matches in two columns of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of filenames. I want to compare every filename in column 1 with every filename in column 2 and if they match, return the value of the cell immediately next to the matched cell in column 2.

Have researched the issue and tried combinations of `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH` without success

```
=INDEX($G$5:$G$263,MATCH(G5,$H$5:$H$400,0))
```

Comment: Based on what you described, sounds like VLOOKUP should work. Why didn't it?

Comment: The formula you provided seems backwards to your description. Maybe edit your question and include actual column letters.

Answer (score 0):

## INDEX MATCH Version

### One version

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0)),"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(B1,A:A,0)))
```

### The Other Way Around Version

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,B:B,0)))
```